# Having 2 pages, How to change the content of a second page by a click event on a button in the first one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, pug

Here is my problem, 
I have a page called page1 (I have a button in this page to access another page called page2).
I want to change the content of a specific selector in page2 by a click event on the button of page1.
Here is my code for page 1 in pug

```
 form#abandonForm(name='btn' action='page2')
  button#abandonBtn.button Abandonner
```

Here is my code for page2 in pug

```
section#termineExam
```

and here is my .js file

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var $abandonBtn = $('#abandonBtn');
  $abandonBtn.click(function(){
    $.get('page2', null, function(data){
    var $data = $(data);
    console.log(data);
    console.log($data.find('#termineExam').html());
    $data.find('#termineExam').text("section changed");
    console.log($data.find('#termineExam').html()); // print the changes
    console.log(data); // print the same data without changes on the section

})
});
});
```

I don't understand why changes are applied on the DOM but not on the page2 itself.
Thank you for helping and sorry for my English!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "but not on the page2 itself"? Are you expecting the changes you make on the client to be actually saved to `page2` on the server?

Comment: I mean that I can't see changes on page2 when I am running the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to misunderstand how `jQuery.get()` works.

From the docs:

> jQuery.get( url [, data ] [, success ] [, dataType ] )
>
> Returns: jqXHR
>
> Description: *Load data from the server* using a HTTP GET request.

Basically, you are getting the content from 'page2' as a string and storing it in a variable named `data`. This is a one way street. When you call `$data.find('#termineExam').text("section changed");` you are modifying the local variable *not the actual page2 file*

When you navigate to `page2`, you are requesting a brand new copy of the `page2` file without any of the modifications that you applied to that string over on page1.

If you want to actually modify the content of `page2`, you'll need some sort of server side script (like php) that accepts new data from page1 and updates the page2 file.

Alternatively, if you just want to send some data to page 2 and have that data appear when that page loads, there are many ways you could do that.

#### One option would be to use `localstorage`:

---

Make a file called `storage.js` with the below content and include this file in both `page1` and `page2`

```
/**
 * Feature detect + local reference for simple use of local storage
 * if (storage) {
 *    storage.setItem('key', 'value');
 *    storage.getItem('key');
 * }
 *
 */
var storage;
var fail;
var uid;
try {
  uid = new Date;
  (storage = window.localStorage).setItem(uid, uid);
  fail = storage.getItem(uid) != uid;
  storage.removeItem(uid);
  fail && (storage = false);
} catch (exception) {}
/* end  Feature detect + local reference */
```

In `page1` do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $abandonBtn = $('#abandonBtn');
  $abandonBtn.click(function() {
      if(storage){
        storage.setItem('termineExam', 'section changed');
      }
  });
});
```

Then, in `page2` do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
      if(storage){
        var text = storage.getItem('termineExam');
        if(text) $('#termineExam').text(text);
      }
});
```

Comment: This doesn't fix my problem.. I want to be able to navigate to page2.